# Background to Scroll Vertically a Certain Amount

Tags: jquery

We've got backgrounds on our site and I was wondering what the easiest way it would be to stop the background scrolling further than a certain amount?

So if you do scroll-y then it's infinite in respect to how much content you have. However how do I stop the BG scrolling after let's say 250px, 100px etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd want to do something like this, I haven't run this code so it may not be perfect, but it should show you the technique (may have also mixed up the 'fixed' and 'scroll' bits - you should be able to tell pretty quickly)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var d = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(d > 250){
        $('#image-div').css('background-attachment', 'fixed');
    }else{
        $('#image-div').css('background-attachment', 'scroll');
    }
});
```

In psuedo code: When the window scrolls, grab a variable (d) equal to the screen 'scrolled' amount, if its over x amount, attach or release the attachment.

Its worth adding this function will fire every time the page is scrolled, there may be methods a bit lighter on processor power, but they're going to look a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Im not quite 100% sure what you mean, but what about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/5245/

It uses jQuery and you can select an amount by such as 250px

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#f').followTo(250);
```

Comment: This is really nice - the css should be changing the background position attachment though I believe (according to the question), not the element position.